# How do you convert an XyzId to an integer in persistent?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

In Persistent, how do you convert an XyzId (PersonId, whateverid) to its representing integer?

Comment: Context: I want to use the identifier within a file name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`unKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.3.1.1/docs/Database-Persist-Types.html#t:KeyBackend) to get [`PersistValue`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.3.1.1/docs/Database-Persist-Types.html#t:PersistValue) from that ident, and get integer from it by pattern matching:

```
intKey ::  PersistEntity val => Key val -> Int64
intKey key = case unKey key of
    PersistInt64 int64 -> int64
    _ -> error "BUG: Unexpected ident"
```

Answer (score 0):

Key is not guaranteed to be integer, but it is guaranteed to be [`PathPiece`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-pieces-0.1.3.1/docs/Web-PathPieces.html#t:PathPiece), and that is much more useful to use in a filename.